# bash string comparison not working as expected - how to fix

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to check if a program is installed on a linux system by comparing command output with an expected output.  I expect the program not to be present and so if program is abc then I should see:

```
bash: abc: command not found
```

But instead I am getting this output:

```
Shell for this session: bash
./checkprogs.sh: line 17: [: too many arguments
addgroup feature enabled test 1
./checkprogs.sh: line 15: tftp: command not found
./checkprogs.sh: line 17: [: too many arguments
tftp feature enabled test 2
2 tests performed
```

Here is the bash code:

```
ourshell="/bin/bash"
ourshell=${ourshell#*bin/}
echo "Shell for this session: $ourshell"

counter=1

# list of programs we want to test if available
progs='addgroup tftp'

for prog in $progs
do
    expected="$ourshell: $prog: command not found"
    #echo "$expected"
    progoutput=$($prog -h)
    #echo "prog output is: $progoutput"
    if [ $expected != $progoutput ]
    then
      echo "test failed"
    fi
    echo "$prog feature enabled test $counter"
    ((counter++))
done

((counter--))
echo "$counter tests performed"
```

How can I fix this?

On the system I am working on, the shell is bash and addgroup is present but tftp is not.

Please note that I am on an embedded platform and "expect" is not installed.  Assume minimal linux installation.

EDIT:
had to add space after [ and before ]  - but even after fixing that still doesn't work as expected.

EDIT:
sorry I am new to bash scripting...

If I quote the strings inside [ ] and add 2>&1 to progoutput then code looks like this:

```
progoutput=$($prog -h 2>&1)    # line 15

if [ "$expected" != "$progoutput" ]    # line 17
```

and just so anyone can try this:

```
progs='ls invalidxxx'     # line 9
```

then output is:

```
Shell for this session: bash
test failed
ls feature enabled test 1
test failed
invalidxxx feature enabled test 2
2 tests performed
```

Comment: Update the error logs you see after you add the spaces around `[` and `]`

Comment: `progoutput=$($prog -h)` should be `progoutput=$($prog -h 2>&1)`

Comment: Could you also quote the variables as `if [ "$expected" != "$progoutput" ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actual method of string comparison

```
if [ "$expected" != "$progoutput" ]
```

or

```
if [[ $expected != $progoutput ]]
```

Comment: That is a partial fix.  But if you run  yourself with eg line : progs='ls invalidxxx' and add 2>&1 to progoutput= line still both tests fail.

Comment: That was helpful so accepting.  Also my expected line had to be changed.